# How to select range of data with start and end dates in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have list of data that includes start and end dates, I want to fetch selected data according to given date range.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a10dfd83aa9c689cb838e4d"),
    "name" : "R1",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-17T20:58:57.191Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-20T20:58:57.191Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a10e0093aa9c689cb838e8e"),
    "name" : "R2",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-10T20:58:57.191Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-25T20:58:57.191Z")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a10e02e3aa9c689cb838ec4"),
    "name" : "R3",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-25T20:58:57.191Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-27T20:58:57.191Z")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a10e06c3aa9c689cb838f18"),
    "name" : "R4",
    "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-15T20:58:57.191Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-18T20:58:57.191Z")
}
```

If fetch start date -"2017-11-16" and end date "2017-11-21" then it should select R1, R2 and R4, Please help me to implement this mongoose query

Comment: Why do you expect R2 in your result set ? Required date range is 2017-11-16 to 2017-11-21 but R3 has 2017-11-10 and 2017-11-25 as start and end dates. Please clarify..

Comment: this is regarding some resource allocation for given duration, then R2 also not available in range so need to fetch it in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below query to get this result, This may helps.

```
db.getCollection.find({ $or: [
{ $and: [{"startDate": {"$lte":ISODate("2017-11-16T20:58:57.191Z")}},{ "endDate": {"$gte": ISODate("2017-11-21T20:58:57.191Z") }}]},
{ $and: [{"startDate": {"$lte":ISODate("2017-11-16T20:58:57.191Z")}},{ "endDate": {"$gte": ISODate("2017-11-16T20:58:57.191Z") }}]},
{ $and: [{"startDate": {"$lte":ISODate("2017-11-21T20:58:57.191Z")}},{ "endDate": {"$gte": ISODate("2017-11-21T20:58:57.191Z") }}]},
{ $and: [{"startDate": {"$gte":ISODate("2017-11-16T20:58:57.191Z")}},{ "endDate": {"$lte": ISODate("2017-11-21T20:58:57.191Z") }}]}
]})
```